# Play App Says Compilation Unit Not On Build Path

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework

I recently got a new computer. I pulled git repository from Heroku containing my Play app but now whenever eclipse tries to autocomplete, I get an alert that pops up saying

> The compilation unit is not on the build path for a Java project.

I went into Project > Properties > Resource > Linked Resources and added the path to my play folder but to no avail.

How can I add Play to eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the `eclipse` (I think play 2.1+) or `eclipsify` (play <=2.0) play commands to create your eclipse project file?

For example:

```
play! 2.1.0 (using Java 1.7.0_17 and Scala 2.10.0), http://www.playframework.org

> Type "help play" or "license" for more information.
> Type "exit" or use Ctrl+D to leave this console.

[mpapi] $ eclipse
[info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
[info] Successfully created Eclipse project files for project(s):
```